# Pass form input (not whole form) object to directive in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to pass `formName.formInput` to a directive so that inside of the directive template I can use `ngMessages='passedFormInput.$error'`

My goal is to create a short cut directive for ngMessages for generic form errors.

I have a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/SakHtD2cCqrzwAssclgp

I want my directive to just require the `<formName>.<inputName>`

```
<form name="form" novalidate>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userEmail">Email Address </label>
        <input ng-model="credentials.email" maxlength="255" required type="email" class="form-control" id="userEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>

    <div rc-messages="form.userEmail"></div>        
</form>
```

Heres my directive:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
})
.directive('rcMessages', function() {

    return {
        require: ['^form', '^rcMessages'],
    restrict: 'A',          // Must be a attributeon a html tag
        template: '<pre><code>formInputError: {{formInputError | json }}</code></pre>' +
          '<pre><code>testForm: {{testForm | json }}</code></pre>' +
          '<div ng-messages="formInputError.$error">' +
          '<span ng-message="required">*</span>' +
          '<span ng-message="minlength">Too short.</span>' +
          '<span ng-message="maxlength">Too long.</span>' +
          '<span ng-message="email">Invalid email address.</span>' +
          '</div>meep',
        scope: false,
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.formInput = $scope.rcMessages;
            console.log('rcMessages', $scope.rcMessages);
            console.log('formInputError', $scope.formInputError);
        }],
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            $scope.testForm = ctrl;
            console.log('ctrl', ctrl);
        }
    };

});
```

I'm able to get the form controller by using `^Form` but I cannot seem to zero in on a particular element in the form.

------ EDIT: SOLUTION for anyone who is looking. -----

I realized my mistake was that I wasnt adding a name to the `input`. When given a name that input object is added to the `FormController` and I was able to access it by sending the input name through the `rc-messages` property.

Please see my updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/u14S269MOIDxvFzHP1Jt

Comment: I'm not sure if would make this any easier, but it seems like it would make much more sense for the directive to be specified on the input itself.

Comment: If it was on the input how could I print a string in the label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the `name` value on your input, that's why you can't access the input's value on the form controller.  You can fix it with this:

```
<input name="userEmail" ng-model="credentials.email" maxlength="255" required 
       type="email" class="form-control" id="userEmail" placeholder="Email">
```

Then inside your `link` function, you can access the `ngModelController` value like so:

```
link: function($scope, elem, attrs, ctrls){
    var inputModel = ctrls[0].userEmail
```

---

By the way, I'm not sure why, but I find this a little suspect:

```
<div rc-messages="form.userEmail">
```

Maybe just give it the key and allow the directive to parse the `formController` for the value of the key `userEmail`?

```
<div rc-messages="userEmail">
```

Just a suggestion.

https://plnkr.co/edit/gcgeT6pzae3UbX7ZWMWi?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what my issue was.